LiDAR Point Cloud Alignment
I am currently using the LiDAR mode on iOS in Polycam to capture scenes and export raw data. While I know that I can directly export point clouds, what I want to do now is generate a point cloud for each image using camera parameters and depth maps, and then simply overlay them to create a complete scene point cloud. I have successfully generated a point cloud for each image, but I encounter a problem when trying to align them, because they are not in world coordinates.
However, the given extrinsic matrix from Polycam raw data export does not really work.
The data specification of the raw data is given here: https://github.com/PolyCam/polyform/tree/main
The iOS ARKit has some coordinate system conventions and I found out this helpful thread with Apple Source Code.
SceneKit point cloud from ARKit depth buffers
However, this does not really work either.
